# Generate the data with desired mean and std, how to restrict the new data points to deviate a maximum of 1 std from the original data points

Tags: python, normal-distribution

The original sample data has the mean(-0.005542) and std (0.06089), but the original data points were ranging between (-0.1208 to 0.14069).

I used the below code to generate new data with desired mean and standard deviation.

But after generating the new data with the desired mean (-0.005542) and std (0.06089), newly generated data points were ranging between (-26.847, 27.9262).

Is there any way to restrict the new data points to deviate a maximum of 1 std from the original data range?

```py
import numpy as np

num_samples = 1000
desired_mean = -0.005542
desired_std_dev = 0.06089

samples = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=desired_std_dev, size=num_samples)

actual_mean = np.mean(samples)
actual_std = np.std(samples)
print("Initial samples stats   : mean = {:.4f} stdv = {:.4f}".format(actual_mean, actual_std))

zero_mean_samples = samples - (actual_mean)

zero_mean_mean = np.mean(zero_mean_samples)
zero_mean_std = np.std(zero_mean_samples)
print("True zero samples stats : mean = {:.4f} stdv = {:.4f}".format(zero_mean_mean, zero_mean_std))

scaled_samples = zero_mean_samples * (desired_std_dev/zero_mean_std)
scaled_mean = np.mean(scaled_samples)
scaled_std = np.std(scaled_samples)
print("Scaled samples stats    : mean = {:.4f} stdv = {:.4f}".format(scaled_mean, scaled_std))

final_samples = scaled_samples + desired_mean
final_mean = np.mean(final_samples)
final_std = np.std(final_samples)
print("Final samples stats     : mean = {:.4f} stdv = {:.4f}".format(final_mean, final_std))
```

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do?  The data tells you what the mean and std dev are.  You don't get to specify the mean and std dev for your data, unless you're generating a fake data stream.

Comment: @Tim Roberts, Yes i have very small observed output, without much shock my data will not deviate too much , and i want to generate a fake data stream to calculate the probability of sample falls less 5% probability assuming it has 5% chance of occurring.

Comment: The code you have above does that, right?  The `final_samples` array matches your requirements.  Where does the +/-27 come from?

Comment: @Tim Robert, yes it does, but it has more width than my original data points(-.12 to 14) so I want to restrict maximum 1 std from my original data points.

Comment: @Tim Robert, +/-27 is from newly generated data

Comment: If I increase number of sample, the width is increasing

Comment: ??? show an example.  If I do `numpy.random.normal(-00.5542,0.06089,100000)`, the numbers get better as the sample size increases.

Comment: @Tim, if you check the minimum and maximum after you increase the number samples, your width will increase with desired mean and std. I am not able to show an example by editing the question due to low reputation points as I am new user.

Comment: You can use `numpy.clip` to get rid of samples outside a given range.  However, doing so will give you a population standard deviation that is less than what you ask.